# C# How can I convert to string from System.IO.StreamReader JSON format

Tags: c#, tostring, streamreader

```
  System.Net.WebRequest req = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(this.url_);
        req.Method = "POST";
        req.Timeout = 100000;
        req.ContentType = "application/json";
        byte[] sentData = Encoding.GetEncoding(1251).GetBytes(this.data_);
        req.ContentLength = sentData.Length;
        System.IO.Stream sendStream = req.GetRequestStream();
        sendStream.Write(sentData, 0, sentData.Length);
        sendStream.Close();
        System.Net.WebResponse res = req.GetResponse();
        System.IO.Stream ReceiveStream = res.GetResponseStream();
        System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(ReceiveStream, Encoding.UTF8);
        //Кодировка указывается в зависимости от кодировки ответа сервера
        Char[] read = new Char[256];
        string value = sr.ReadToEnd();
        int count = sr.Read(read, 0, 256);
        string Out = String.Empty;
        while (count > 0)
        {
            String str = new String(read, 0, count);
            string s = new string(read);
            Out += str;
            requestedData_ += s;
            count = sr.Read(read, 0, 256);
        }
        return Out;
```

I need JSON format like

```
{"object":{"1":"DEPO Name","244":"Lviv","245":"Lviv","246":"Lviv_2","247":"Lviv_2","248":"Lviv_2","249":"Lviv_2"},"errors":[],"fields":{}}
```

but it return

```
"{\"object\":{\"1\":\"DEPO Name\",\"244\":\"Lviv\",\"245\":\"Lviv\",\"246\":\"Lviv_2\",\"247\":\"Lviv_2\",\"248\":\"Lviv_2\",\"249\":\"Lviv_2\"},\"errors\":[],\"fields\":{}}"
```

How fix it?

here you will see 
http://json2csharp.com/

i cant convert

```
PostTemplate value = new PostTemplate(this.url_ + url, data);
            string result = value.GetData();
            AddedDepoId returnId = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AddedDepoId>
(result);
```

I read POST answer(is JSON format)

Comment: Where do you see that its "{\"? if its the debugger, well if you use `Console.Writeline()` it will be correct. Thats escaping " with \ so it actually writes " where it should be.

Comment: That being said, to align with common standards, I'd advise you to reconsider your syntax. For example, private fields are usually defined as *_privateField* not *privateField_* 
Your casing is inconsistent (i.e String and string)
Also, you may want to use StringBuilder instead of string as string type is immutable and if your while loop might cause your code to be slow.

Comment: thanks for "private fields are usually defined as _privateField not privateField_" 
I wrote at C++, GoogleSyle

Answer (score 0):

I assume you watched onto the value in the debugger.

The string is correct, and its values are [escaped](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw.aspx)

Use `Console.Writeline` to check out the value.

Comment: I need convert it from JSON to Class, but it have " and \ 
http://json2csharp.com/
Yes, the value in the debugger. 
it web application

Comment: try to save it to a file with `File.WriteAllLines` Then you have it without the " and \. You can also display it on your web app and copy it